# RStudio: Prepackaged datasets are missing

Tags: r, rstudio

I am following code examples, and need to load in prepackaged datasets such as iris into my environment. However, executing `data()` in RStudio brings up no results.

Answer (score 0):

The iris dataset is in the base R package `datasets`. If `data()` does not work I would try the following:

```
library(datasets)
data(package = "datasets")
```

Otherwise, you can use the datasets provided by other packages. Try the following to see all the datasets from packages currently available to you:

```
data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))
```

If the above does not work I would consider uninstalling and reinstalling R, because the base packages weren't properly installed. Hope this helps!